# Android - Convert ARGB Color to RGB

Tags: java, android, colors, rgb, rgba

I'm trying to get the rgb value of a color with alpha, meaning make it full opaque with different red, green and blue values.

For example,

```
Color.argb(204, 40, 40, 40) // I have this color
Color.rgb(48, 48, 48) // I expect this value
```

I've tried converting argb to HEX, and after HEX to rgb, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input is a translucent color and you expect a slightly brighter output. That can be achieved by overlaying your input over white.

support-v4 library contains [`ColorUtils.compositeColors`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html#compositeColors(int,%20int)) which does what you need:

```
final int input = Color.argb(204, 40, 40, 40);
final int output = ColorUtils.compositeColors(input, Color.WHITE);
```